# Flutter Websocket using STOMP - message not receiving

Tags: android, spring-boot, flutter, websocket, stomp

I am trying to build a simple WebSocket application using Flutter and Spingboot as a WebSocket server. I can send messages but the subscription is not working. Not able to receive the message.

Flutter Code

```
dynamic onConnect(StompClient client, StompFrame frame) {
client.subscribe(
  destination: '/topic/messages/',
  callback: (StompFrame frame) {
    List<dynamic> result = json.decode(frame.body);
    print(result);
  });
}

final stompClient = StompClient(
 config: StompConfig(
 url: 'ws://xx.xx.xx.xx:xxxx/websocket-chat',
 onConnect: onConnect,
 onWebSocketError: (dynamic error) => print(error.toString()),
 stompConnectHeaders: {},
 webSocketConnectHeaders: {},
 ),
);


//sending
stompClient.send(destination: '/app/chat', body: "das");
```

Spring Controller

```
@MessageMapping("/chat")
@SendTo("/topic/messages")
public Message sendMessage(String message) {
    System.out.println("handling send message");
    return new Message("message");
}
```

"handling send message" is printing on the console but the message is not.

Comment: Do you mind sharing your Spring Socket config? Might be helpful in determining what goes wrong.